# Error while getting resultset

Tags: java, resultset

I have a class in which i am getting resultset from the database:

```
public ResultSet GetDataFromDB() {
    ResultSet resultset = null;
    try {   
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());   
        System.out.println("Connecting to the database...");   
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:DBname", "user123","pass123");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();   
        resultset = statement.executeQuery("select * from tablename"); 

        while (resultset.next()) {
            System.out.println(resultset.getInt(1) + " " +
            resultset.getInt(2) + " " + 
            resultset.getInt(3) + " " + 
            resultset.getString(4));
        }
        // statement.close();   
        //connection.close(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {   
        System.out.println("The exception raised is:" + e);   
    }

    return resultset;
}
```

In this classs i am able to print the data which i am getting in resultset. but when i tried to get this resultset in another class:

```
Classname obj= new Classname();
ResultSet tempResultSet = obj.GetDataFromDB();
System.out.println("Records Exist "+tempResultSet.next()); <-----false
```

I am not getting any data here.
also there is no datatable here in java like in .net so that i can use that...Please concern
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (resultset.next()) {
```

You already read all of the data from the `ResultSet` in this loop.

`ResultSet` is a single-use, forward-only view of the data; you can only iterate it once.

Comment: thanks.. thats a sort of weird that we can use it only once  :)

Comment: @Aquarius24: No; it's not weird.  `ResultSet` does not store the results in memory; instead, it streams them directly from the database.  Otherwise, it would consume large amounts of memory.

Comment: Ok but there should be a "datatable" sort of component so that we can use it anytime and n number of times.